# oracle apex page stops execution after calling report query

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an oracle apex page that saves the data to a table while page processing ,when a button is clicked. After this I call a report query and generates a pdf report.After the pdf report is generated, the page stops execution without completing the page submit action. Hence the page items do not get refreshed and the page do not reloads. The control goes to the newly generated pdf report. Anybody have a solution for this?

**Edit**

A button 'SAVE' is created for calling the report query 'SLIP'. Then inside the page a dynamic action is created . javascript code is written inside DA. This javascript will submit the button using the code

```
apex.submit('SAVE')
```

A pl/sql page process  is also created for this save button. This will work after above JavaScript code is executed at point 'processing'. After this, report query 'SLIP' is called and pdf report is generated and it is opened in adobe reader. Then the page stops executoin, page do not gets submitted . The page item values will not be cleared and the page do not reloads. That is the issue I'm facing

Comment: Please provide more information about your components and their properties. Do you use (and how) processes, dymanic actions, ajax callbacks, etc.

Comment: Hi sir. I have updated this now

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript Code:

```
apex.submit('BUTTONNAME');
```

Comment: I have used this as button dynamic action and there is a page process after this js code. All these works but after the pdf report generation, page stops execution and does not reloads with refreshed page item values as said in the question.